# Faster JsonCpp alternative that allows copying/mutability of Json objects?

Tags: c++, json, c++11, jsoncpp, rapidjson

JsonCpp is slow. And the code is pretty messy.

Is there any alternative that is faster, cleaner and supports stuff like:

```
Json::Value val, copy;
val["newMember"] = 100;
val["newMember2"] = "hello";
copy = val;
val["newMember2"] = "bye";
assert(val["newMember"] == copy["newMember"]);
assert(val["newMember2"] != copy["newMember2"]);
```

JsonCpp supports code like the one above.

I've tried **rapidjson**, which is **very** fast, but unfortunately it does not support copying Json values.

Any alternative? Bonus point for benchmarks.

Comment: Do you want to store JSON or do is OK to translate JSON text into C++ structures.

Comment: Would this work for you: http://pastebin.com/LwH92T3w

Comment: @LokiAstari I want to store JSON objects like jsoncpp does

Comment: You might look at the C++ API in [JPJson](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/JPJson), which is the core of its Objective-C API. It can generate a representation with standard containers and basically support the syntax you requested. It's quite fast as well - comparable to rapidjson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching for some time the "documentation" I finally found a good way to copy JSON objects with rapidjson wich is very convenient:

```
rapidjson::Document doc; // This is the base document that you got from parsing etc
rapidjson::Value& v = doc["newMember"]; // newMember = 100

assert(v.GetInt() == 100);

rapidjson::Document copy;
doc.Accept(copy); // The accept meachnism is the same as used in parsing, but for copying

assert(copy["newMember"].GetInt() == doc["newMember"].GetInt())
```

The explicit copying has one advantage: It forces you to think clearly about when you are using references or potentially unnecessary copies.

Comment: It raises a lot of `C2248` errors when compiling, of a lot of elements inside the `Accept` function saying all the same message: `cannot access private member declared in class 'rapidjson::GenericDocument<Enconding>'`. I'm using `doc.Accept(other.doc)` in the copy constructor. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Recently, a contribution added deep-copying API to rapidjson. https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/pull/20